# Deploy in IBM Bluemix

Tags: deployment, ibm-cloud, host

Preparing to start the job...
Downloading build artifacts...
Target: https://api.ng.bluemix.net
Creating service instance simple-rbs-cloudantNoSQLDB in org foodue / space dev as inopark95@gmail.com...
OK
Service simple-rbs-cloudantNoSQLDB already exists
Using manifest file /home/pipeline/f1a258a3-836b-4192-9f3d-c81f0e0448bf/manifest.yml

Creating app simple-rbs-foodue in org foodue / space dev as inopark95@gmail.com...
OK

Creating route simple-rbs.mybluemix.net...
OK

FAILED
Server error, status code: 400, error code: 210003, message: The host is taken: simple-rbs

Finished: FAILED

It says the host is already taken. Do you have any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `host is already taken` error means that either you or another user are already using that hostname and it is not available for use.  To use a different hostname, modify your `manifest.yml` file to specify what host to use, or remove the `host` parameter to default to using `<your-app-name>.mybluemix.net`.

Example manifest.yml file specifying hostname of my-simple-rbs-hostname.mybluemix.net:

```
---
applications:
 - name: simple-rbs
   host: my-simple-rbs-hostname
   domain: mybluemix.net
```

See the [Deploying with Application Manifests](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#host) for more information on options in the `manifest.yml` file.